# Creating a table using Group By

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using Microsoft Access 2016.

I have a table like this:

```
Column_1   Status
    a       Fail
    b       Pass
    a       Not tested
    c       Fail
    c       Pass
```

I want to create a query that will get me:

```
Column_1   Fail Not tested  Pass 
    a        1       1       0   
    b        0       0       1    
    c        1       0       1
```

I want to be able to count how many times a `Status` appears per unique `Column_1` type. This to me seems like a `GROUP BY` case but I am having trouble getting the proper counts per status.

Here is one attempt:

```
SELECT [c1],
COUNT(IIF (Status='Pass', 1, 0) ) As Pass,
COUNT(IIF (Status='Fail', 1, 0) ) As Fail,
COUNT(IIF (Status='Not tested', 1, 0) ) As [Not tested]
FROM table_1
GROUP BY  [c1]
```

This however, gives me the same counts in all 3 columns. And the counts aren't correct either. I thought about including `Status` in my `GROUP BY` clause but that only increases the number of rows or records in my result by repeating `a` and/or `b` per status which is not what I want. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Counting 1 or counting 0 will return 1 every time.  You could use sum instead.

Comment: @Andrew Welp, that did it. Thanks for opening my eyes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Access you should be able to create a CrossTab query to give your desired results:

```
TRANSFORM Count(tblTest.Status) AS CountOfStatus
SELECT tblTest.Column_1
FROM tblTest
GROUP BY tblTest.Column_1
PIVOT tblTest.Status;
```

Alternatively you can do a manual cross tab either changing your aggregate functions from count to sum or by changing the last parameter of your iif function to null, or both:

```
SELECT tblTest.Column_1,
Sum(IIf([Status]='Fail',1,0)) AS Fail,
Count(IIf([Status]='Not Tested',1,Null)) AS [Not tested],
Sum(IIf([Status]='Pass',1,Null)) AS Pass
FROM tblTest
GROUP BY tblTest.Column_1;
```

Comment: This worked to more or less give me what I wanted and is a more elegant solution than my hard coding but I also have a "<>" column which is causing issues. Is that because of my table?

Comment: If your Status column has a record with '<>' then you would end up with a cross tab that includes a column with that name unless you filter it out. `where status <> '<>'`

Comment: Gotcha then that must be the `Null` or empty space? Because my test table that I'm working with has some status rows that are simply not filled out yet. You gave me plenty of food for thought as I am inexperienced at SQL and never used `PIVOT` before.

Answer (score 0):

I would do two queries - First a query to use totals functions to group and count each column you want.

```
SELECT tblTest.Column_1, tblTest.Status, Count(tblTest.Status) AS CountOfStatus
FROM tblTest
GROUP BY tblTest.Column_1, tblTest.Status;
```

Then a query that reads the first query and formats your data however you would like.

Comment: Hmm, I have been able to get what I want using Andrew's advice in the comments of simply replacing what I had with `SUM` and this does not give me the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

so before you head down the path of a Cross Tab - - consider that the 1s and 0s that you display in your original post do not exist in the database.  Your preferred layout is indeed Cross Tab but it is not the normalized data structure that databases use - which is why you may want to reconsider your approach.

If you use an Aggregate Query you can group and count; while maintaining normalized data structure.  It is much easier to manage as a developer.  In this case you would have:
   ID        Status          Count
    a       Fail               1
    a       Not tested         1
    b       Pass               1
    c       Fail               1
    c       Pass               1
[sorry not keeping the columnar display as in the message box]

You can do a little online tutoring about the Aggregate Query.  It is not going to count 0 for non existing records.  But if you are flexible on this presentation it is a much simpler implementation.